# Remove view of UIViewController from UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

When user click on add button, I'm adding view on UIWindow. Now If user clicks on add button again I want to first remove that view and add it again.

**I have used this code to add view on UIWindow :**

```
ProgressVC *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDProgressVC"];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] addSubview:vc.view];
```

**For Remove I have tried this code :**

```
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] setNeedsLayout];
vc = nil;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the issue..

Comment: @RohitKP that view is still appear in UIWindow.

Comment: Why don't you set a property for UIVIew which holds the vc.view, and you can use the property to remove the view ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri that view is not property of vc. It is main view of `ProgressVC`.

Comment: @EktaMakadiya if you are removing the view in some other function, you need property, I suspect two things, vc which is added had a different reference, and the  one you are removing has another.. Better to have it as property, and use it.

Comment: I meant to say that declare a property and use it add or remove the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
// Make this global property

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView * currentView;

//store the view in gloabal property
ProgressVC *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDProgressVC"];
currentView = vc.view;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] addSubview:currentView];

//remove it 
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] setNeedsLayout];
currentView = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both `vc` is same object not different.

I mean when you add vc.view at that time you alloc and init object and when you remove then again you alloc and init then both are different instance of same class.

So it's better to declare instance variable or property like,

`ProgressVC *vc` and alloc it only once and add or remove this vc from window.

It may solve your issue i think.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.2

```
let storybord = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

let vc = storybord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDProgressVC")
               as IDProgressVC

currentVC = vc.view

appDelegate.window?.addSubview(currentVC!)

// Remove it
currentVC?.removeFromSuperview()

appDelegate.window?.setNeedsLayout()

currentVC = nil
```

Comment: This line is important "appDelegate.window?.setNeedsLayout()"